# TSQL: Multiple IF conditions in a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

Hope I can get suggestions.

I created a stored procedure, but it is not working as intended. Basically if a value exists in a table then it will just select it, else it will insert rows to that table.

TABLE_A -- This is where I need to check if the code exists

| CODE | LETTER |
| --- | --- |
| GREEEN | A |
| YELLOW | B |

TABLE_B -- I use this table to get letters, there are only 2 groups.

| GROUP | LETTERS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |

This is the stored procedure I made

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_CODE

DECLARE
 @CODE VARCHAR(5) = 'RED'
,@GROUP INT       = '1'

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
 @GROUPID dbo.UniqueID 
,@COUNT = (SELECT count(Code) from TABLE_A where [Code] = @CODE)

/** Get letters **/

        IF @GROUP = '1'
        begin
            insert into @GROUPID
            select LETTERS from TABLE B
                where GROUP = @GROUP
        end

    else IF @GROUP = '2'

        begin
            insert into @GROUPID
            select LETTERS from TABLE B
                where GROUP = @GROUP
        end



/** if not exists insert, else go to next step **/

       IF @COUNT = 0
              begin
                        insert into TABLE_A VALUES
                        select
                              @CODE
                             ,LETTERS
                        FROM @GROUPid
              end

/** select where @code **/

     SELECT * FROM TABLE_A where CODE = @CODE

END
```

Works well if the code exist, but if the code does not exist, it does not insert to TABLE_A

Comment: Asides: Assigning a string (`'1'`) rather than a numeric value (`1`) to an `int` variable is part of a bad habit. Comparing an `int` to a string (`@GROUP = '2'`) doesn't help. When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`exists`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than getting an exact [`count`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You're sproc is never going to insert into TABLE_A because you did not tell it to. You are inserting into the variable @GROUPID.

This will create a temporary table (note the #) and populate it with a row

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table_a
CREATE TABLE #table_a (code NVARCHAR(10), groupID INT)
INSERT INTO #table_a (code, groupID) VALUES
('Green', 2)

SELECT *
  FROM #table_a
```

```
code    groupID
---------------
Green   2
```

If we then do what you're attempting (outside of a stored procedure for now):

```
DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(10) = 'Red', @groupID INT = 1

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #table_a WHERE @code = code AND groupID = @groupID)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #table_a (code, groupID) VALUES
 (@code, @groupID)
END

SELECT *
  FROM #table_a
 WHERE code = @code
   AND groupID = @groupID
```

```
code    groupID
---------------
Red     1
```

First we declare some variables, and give them values.
Then we look to see if the values exist in the table using NOT EXISTS.
If that returns true we INSERT those values into #table_a.
Since we now know that they will exist (they either did already, or we just inserted them) we can then just select those values.

If we do the same thing again, but this time with existing values we can see it doesn't insert them again:

```
SET @code = 'Red'
SET @groupID = 1

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #table_a WHERE @code = code AND groupID = @groupID)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #table_a (code, groupID) VALUES
 (@code, @groupID)
END

SELECT *
  FROM #table_a
 WHERE code = @code
   AND groupID = @groupID
```

```
code    groupID
Red     1
```